# Can not recieve data when use retrofit and set minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, proguard

I try to get data from server with android, i work well when is set **minifyEnabled false** but when i set **minifyEnabled true** i can not revice data, it all is null

My version java is 17, My retrosit version is

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0
com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0
com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0
```

I try some other answer on stackoverflow

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}
```

My code to call api

```
interface ApiService {
    @POST("/ipay-decode/")
    suspend fun handleDataTest(
        @Body requestBody: BaseRequest,
    ): BaseResponse
}

data class BaseRequest(
    @SerializedName("encrypted")
    val encrypted: String
)

open class BaseResponse {
    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String = ""
}
```

Can anyone help me with any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your models getting obfuscated when minify is enabled. To fix  add the path to your models package to your Proguard rules.

Something like this should work:

```
-keep class your.package.name.model.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    private void readObjectNoData();
    Object writeReplace();
    Object readResolve();
}
```